# Where programmers ask business questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, business

I remember finding an ad of some kind to a stackoverflow-style site that was for programmers to ask business questions. Anybody know of it? What is the name/url?

Comment: --> http://startups.com/

Answer (score 2):

You mean [startups.com](http://startups.com)?

Answer (score 0):

[Joel's Business Of Software](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/?biz) is a pretty good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [startups proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) on area51 for this that will soon enter private beta.

Comment: Note to future visitors: the bid for Startups to be a StackExchange site failed.